# Is creating Spring prototype beans faster than creating singletons?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

Is a prototype bean created faster by the spring container than a singleton bean? How much if yes?

Maybe some background for the question. Assume that we have the context definition which contains a lot of bean definitions. And the application is a 'short running task' I wonder if I can speed up creation of the context by defining all beans as prototypes - because in this case it doesn't matter if they are singletons or not.

Comment: I might suggest that they take the same *amount* of time to create, but in general, a `singleton` scope bean will be *fetched* each time it is requested from the application context, while a `prototype` bean will need to be *created* each time it is requested from the application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches are completely different in the amount of beans created.

- When the bean has a `scope="prototype"` this means a **new** bean instance will be created everytime you ask for a bean with the corresponding `id`.
- When the bean doesn't have a `scope` attribute set, this means a single instance will be created when the context is loaded for the first time and will be shared.

I believe the time consumed for creation of prototype and singleton beans is (if not the same) very close.

Comment: Yes I know the what the difference between prototype and singleton is. The question is about time. Singleton beans are fully managed by IOC container that is why I wonder if creation process of singleton takes more.

Comment: I think they both re-use the same "creating of a bean source code"